# Is there a way that i can remove THIS index?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to remove this element/index when the time passes.

```
mainArrayOfQueues[iOfChan].push({ "userId": userId, "userName" : userName, "userRank": rank, "voteState" : 0,  "idle" : setTimeout(function () {       
            //When the time passes I want to remove this element (index);
            }, time)});
```

Comment: Is `idle` supposed to be a function or the result of `setTimeout` ?

Comment: This is what idle is https://snag.gy/u9HCeK.jpg , i want that every player have a timeout when they queue and kick him after a while, like he is afk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push` method returns the index of the element, so you can save that in a variable and use it in the timeout function.

```
var index = mainArrayOfQueues[iOfChan].push({
  "userId": userId,
  "userName": userName,
  "userRank": rank,
  "voteState": 0,
  "idle": setTimeout(function() {
    mainArrayOfQueues[iOfChan].splice(index, 1);
  }, time)
});
```

However, this has the problem that indexes will change if other elements preceding it have been removed before this timeout occurs. A better solution would be to remember the object itself, then search the array for it and remove it.

```
var obj = {
  "userId": userId,
  "userName": userName,
  "userRank": rank,
  "voteState": 0,
  "idle": setTimeout(function() {
    var index = mainArrayOfQueues[iOfChan].indexOf(obj);
    if (index != -1) {
      mainArrayOfQueues[iOfChan].splice(index, 1);
    }
  }, time)
};
mainArrayOfQueues[iOfChan].push(obj);
```

Comment: Thank You, it helped me a lot ^^.
Know its working fine